# Do SQL mapping tables speed up queries? How do you use them?

Tags: mysql, sql-optimization

I'd like to know what the purpose of a mapping table is, and how it speeds up MySQL queries. I am working on speeding up a slow MySQL query, and I ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923438/mysql-subselect-alternative) stackoverflow question. Comments suggest that not only do mapping tables speed queries up that join both tables, but that they are the proper way to structure a database.

I have a table structure that is very similar, with a one-to-many relationship. As the table grows, the query execution time continues to climb to unacceptable levels. Since I haven't been able to find much on the web to help solve my problem, I though I'd try stackoverflow, since you guys have never let me down.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the answer regarding perf. The answer had to do with Not In Vs Not Exists which is discussed at length in [Quassnoi's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/55159/quassnoi) article  [IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/) and not "mapping tables"

Comment: so a mapping table wouldn't affect my query time then - that didn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Wouldn't make much sense to me either, unless there's some weird perf hit having to do with the width of the values in an index. I recommend that you take a look at the [query execution plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and see where the bottle neck is.

Comment: Ultimately the problem was more basic than I expected (I'm not an SQL expert). Apparently using a previously referenced table as a subquery in the where clause can be abysmally slow - I solved the problem by creating a temporary table and using that in its stead. If anyone can offer a simple explain of how that helps, I'll up-vote their comment.

Comment: Well you can try and use EXPLAIN EXTENDED to see what the differences are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know what the purpose of a mapping table is

A mapping table is used to represent a "many to many" relationship. For instance, in the question you quoted, there are two entities - books and students. A student may borrow many books; a book may be borrowed by many students.

The standard way to represent this in the relational model is through a "mapping table", which would have foreign keys to books and students, together with any information related to the loan - start and end date, for instance.

A mapping table is indeed a "proper" way to model many to many relationships.

> and how it speeds up MySQL queries

It doesn't in most cases, though it usually performs better than other ways of representing "many to many" relationships. If performance is your concern, @Namphibian's answer is on the money as a starting point.

Comment: So a mapping table isn't really useful in a one to many relationship? It sounds like I either misread or was misled by the question I referenced.

Answer (score 4):

The firs thing you need to answer is why the query is running so slow. Assuming you have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID= 1
```

It is running slow. So how do you determine why it is running slow? Type the following:

```
EXPLAIN ALL SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID=1
```

This will return a result set indicating how MySQL is getting to the data. Here you can find clues about missing indexes etc which can help optimize your queries.

See the following links for more answers:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

[MySQL table index optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137358/mysql-table-index-optimization/10137481#10137481)

Even if you used a mapping table and your queries and indexing is not optimal you will have abysmal performance.